# JQuery autocomplete plugins - how do they compare?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, compare

There are several options for autocomplete for JQuery:

1. jQuery UI autocomplete  - [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
2. LoopJ TokenInput - [link](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)
3. jQuery textboxlist - [link](http://www.devthought.com/projects/jquery/textboxlist/)

Do you have an experience with any two of them to be able to compare? How do they compare? Which one did you choose and what are the factors was to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as "not constructive." Just my two cents is that jQueryUI autocomplete is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the latter two but I know the benefit of the first is that you can link to the google libraries version, along with the jQuery script itself. http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html. Basically a lot of websites link to the same file so most users have it cached in their browser. That means that they don't even have to download the script to run it.

Comment: I don't know if the other scripts allow you to utilize HTML in the list items but I have discovered that the jQuery AI one doesn't. To enable this visit https://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-html-in-autocomplete.